# Any data on average income by district in Seoul, South Korea?

Tags: data-request, income, korea

I would like to access to any data on average income (or average household income or disposable income or whatever other similar statistics) depending on each district in Seoul, South Korea.

If the data includes other districts in other cities such as Daegu or Busan, it sounds amazing.

Is there anyone that knows this kind of data source?

Comment: I work at Quandl and we have this database that shows household income statistics for South Korea. It might not be as granular/specific as you'd like, but figured I'd share anyway in case: https://www.quandl.com/data/SGE?keyword=income%20south%20korea (Also, it's a premium database, not a free database).